# How do you create a hidden div that doesn't create a line break or horizontal space?

Tags: html, hidden

I want to have a hidden checkbox that doesn't take up any space on the screen.

If I have this:

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="visibility: hidden">
```

I don't see the checkbox, but it still creates a new line.

If I have this:

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="visibility: hidden; display:inline;">
```

it no longer creates a new line, but it takes up horizontal space on the screen.

Is there a way to have a hidden div that takes up no room (vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Is there any use for such a div?

Comment: @Jonno: It's commonly used in AJAX.  Say you have a list of items with disclosure triangles.  You want details, or a subtree, to appear when the user clicks the disclosure triangle.  So what you do is put a <div id="theID" style="display: none;"> where the details should go.  Then, when the user clicks the triangle, you move the triangle to a "halfway" position (pointing southeast) and fire off an AJAX request to fill in the <div>.  When the AJAX request finishes, you turn the triangle south and remove the "display: none;" from the <div>'s style.  The script.aculo.us library does this a lot.

Answer (score 842, accepted):

Use `display:none;`

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
```

- `visibility: hidden` hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.
- `display: none` removes the element completely from the document, it doesn't take up any space.

Comment: to show the div again (just in case anybody needs as did I) - `<div id="divCheckbox" style="display: inline-block;">`

Comment: @anujin: Why `inline-block`? The default `display` value for a div is `block`!

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite? To change a div from `display: none` to `display: inline-block` or equivalent without the now-displayed div taking up space and moving my other DOM elements around?

Comment: might be worth updating the answer to include the global HTML attribute [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) which is available since [HTML5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) which is basically the same as saying `display: none` although straight from HTML. However any use of the `display` property overrides the behavior of the `hidden` global attribute.

Answer (score 93):

Since the release of [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) one can now simply do:

```
<div hidden>This div is hidden</div>
```

**Note:** This is not [supported](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=hidden) by some old browsers, most notably IE < 11.

*Hidden* Attribute Documentation  ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden),[W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute))

Comment: This is more semantically correct than hiding with CSS, it's better for accessibility, and it's supported by all major browsers. It should be the accepted answer in 2020.

Comment: how does this this compare to display: none, especially considering a fade out animation?

Answer (score 30):

Use `style="display: none;"`.  Also, you probably don't need to have the DIV, just setting the style to `display: none` on the checkbox would probably be sufficient.

Comment: I need to hide me alert msg on page load and wanted to show it again on button click. Tried `visibility: hidden` but that was showing empty space. `style="display: none;"` worked like a little charm :)

Answer (score 12):

To prevent the checkbox from taking up any space **without** removing it from the DOM, use [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute.

```
<div hidden id="divCheckbox">
```

To prevent the checkbox from taking up any space and **also** removing it from the DOM, use [`display: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box).

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you should focus on usability and generalities in CSS, rather than use an id to point to a specific layout element (which results in huge or multiple css files) you should probably instead use a true class in your linked .css file:

```
.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
}
```

or for the minimalist:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Now you can simply apply it via:

```
<div class="hidden"> content </div>
```

Comment: code looks a lot cleaner this way! I prefer having a class over inline style

Comment: "visibility: hidden;" is exactly what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In addition to CMS´ answer you may want to consider putting the style in an external stylesheet and assign the style to the id, like this:

```
#divCheckbox {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 , that's really a good suggestion ,but how to show only one checkbox without affecting all other checkboxes visibility ?

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Old question but there should be an answer here. You have a css class called invis and you add/remove it from the checkbox or div by id using JS.

Answer (score 6):

To only *hide the element **visually** but keep it in the html*, you can use:

```
<div style='visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden; height:0; width:0;'>
  [content]
</div>
```

or

```
<div style='visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden; position:absolute;'>
  [content]
</div>
```

What ***may go wrong with `display:none`***? It removes the element from the html completely, so some functionalities will be broken if they need to access the hidden element content.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `<span>` to isolate small segments of markup to be styled without breaking up layout. This would seem to be more idiomatic than trying to force a `<div>` not to display itself--if in fact the checkbox itself cannot be styled in the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

**Show / hide by mouse click:**

```
<script language="javascript">

    function toggle() {

        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
        var text = document.getElementById("displayText");

        if (ele.style.display == "block") {

            ele.style.display = "none";
            text.innerHTML = "show";
        }
        else {

            ele.style.display = "block";
            text.innerHTML = "hide";
        }
    }
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here

<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>
```

Source: [Here](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
display: none;
```

This should make the element disappear and not take up any space.

Comment: Thank you to the people that commented on the formatting of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#divCheckbox {display: none;}

This should solve it