# JavaScript and Hide div not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to hide the dive using style property of div i.e.

```
    <div id="<%=divCount%>" style="display: block" hidden>
```

But it is not working.
 And I am also writing a script in the head for hiding/showing divs. It is also not working

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function showAccount(divId){    document.getElementById(divId.value).style.display = "none";    echo divId.value; }
```

How Do I fix it?
`

Comment: just leave the **hidden** property and remove the style attr.

Answer (score 3):

From this link: [How do you create a hidden div that doesn't create a line break or horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992114/how-do-you-create-a-hidden-div-that-doesnt-create-a-line-break-or-horizontal-sp)
It looks like the `hidden` tag, it should be
`<div id="<%=divCount%>" style="display: block visibility: hidden">`

For JavaScript, you shouldn't be changing the display element, but from here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

You should be doing `document.getElementById(divId.value).style.visibility = "hidden";`