# Hidden divs make my site too long

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div id="content" style="visibility: hidden;">
<!-- 500 lines of HTML --->
</div>
```

This div contain divs that are shown via Javascript. The problem is that it makes my site's height too big even if nothing is shown.

I know I could just add the divs to be generated in the Javascript file, but I wonder if there is a CSS solution, since I like to have the "skeleton" in the HTML instead of the Javascript.

Comment: why not use `style="display: none"` - am I missing something?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I didn't know that existed, I never do frontend. Sorry.

Comment: @MihaiT "how to hide divs" gave me visibility:hidden.

Comment: how to hide divs gives me this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992114/how-do-you-create-a-hidden-div-that-doesnt-create-a-line-break-or-horizontal-sp

anyway . try more than the first link google gives you :) Possible duplicate of [How do you create a hidden div that doesn't create a line break or horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992114/how-do-you-create-a-hidden-div-that-doesnt-create-a-line-break-or-horizontal-sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style="display: none"` in the css

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`.

If you want to make it visible again, simply change it to `display:block;`.